# CocoaPods with Realm

Tags: ios, cocoapods, realm

I am trying to use CocoaPods to install Realm. I have done it before with no problem but now I am getting an error. Below I posted my Podfile code and the error I am getting back in Terminal

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!


target 'Htlaeh' do

    pod 'RealmSwift'

end

target 'HtlaehTests' do

    'pod RealmSwift'

end

target 'HtlaehUITests' do

    pod 'RealmSwift'

end
```

**Error**

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
target 'Htlaeh' do
              ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

#  from /Users/Cody/Desktop/Htlaeh/Podfile:7
#  -------------------------------------------
#  
>  target 'Htlaeh' do
#  
#  -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can see two potential syntax errors in there that CocoaPods wouldn't be happy about:

1. `Uncomment this line if you're using Swift` needs to be commented out (It was referring to the line below it. ;) )
2. In the `Tests` target, it should be `pod 'RealmSwift'`. The apostrophe is in front of 'pod' right now.

Please try correcting those two syntax issues, and if that doesn't fix it, let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks @TiM I did it like that and it took forever to update. I don't know if my internet is crazy slow now or what. I figured that line looked dumb too. Do you work at the SF office for Realm? I saw your github and SO profile say Perth.

Comment: No worries Cody! I'm glad that worked (since I would have had no clue what else it would have been!). Yeah, I'm wondering now if those instructions should be re-worded to be a bit more specific. Haha, that's right. I live in Perth, and I work for Realm remotely. :)

Comment: Dang nevermind I am going to be at the Realm SF office next Thursday and was going to see if you wanted to grab coffee. I just tweeted you.